# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane

Tags: java, hbase

We use HBase Java client to read and write data to HBase service running in GCP Dataproc cluster. Recently we update Java version, HBase client version and Spring boot version.

```
Java runtime version from 8 to 17

HBase shaded client version from 2.2.4 to 2.5.4

Spring boot version from 2.13 to 3.1.0

Environment : Docker image in Kubernetes. Runtime docker image openjdk:17.0.2-jdk-slim
```

Client connect to server sometimes but it getting failed mostly.

Error message

```
java.io.IOException: Call to address=150.1.3.7:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor41.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$300(AbstractRpcClient.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$RpcChannelImplementation.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$Stub.scan(ClientProtos.java:45339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncClientScanner.callOpenScanner(AsyncClientScanner.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.call(AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.lambda$doCall$7(AsyncSingleRequestRpcRetryingCaller.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncRegionLocator.lambda$null$5(AsyncRegionLocator.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionUtils.lambda$getOrFetch$4(ConnectionUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZKConnectionRegistry.tryComplete(ZKConnectionRegistry.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZKConnectionRegistry.lambda$getMetaRegionLocation$2(ZKConnectionRegistry.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZKConnectionRegistry.lambda$getAndConvert$0(ZKConnectionRegistry.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FutureUtils.lambda$addListener$0(FutureUtils.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1.exec(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient.run(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:344)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.toIOE(IPCUtil.java:159)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.provider.BuiltInProviderSelector.configure(BuiltInProviderSelector.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.provider.SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.instantiateSelector(SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.provider.SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.instantiate(SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.provider.SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.getInstance(SaslClientAuthenticationProviders.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcConnection.<init>(RpcConnection.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.<init>(NettyRpcConnection.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcClient.createConnection(NettyRpcClient.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcClient.createConnection(NettyRpcClient.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.lambda$getConnection$0(AbstractRpcClient.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.PoolMap.createResource(PoolMap.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.PoolMap$RoundRobinPool.getOrCreate(PoolMap.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.PoolMap.getOrCreate(PoolMap.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.getConnection(AbstractRpcClient.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:443)
    ... 39 common frames omitted"
```

After revert to old versions application is working without any issue.

Same Java and HBase shaded clients versions are working on Plain java (Not Spring boot) applications.

How I solve this.

Comment: PLease share the last `caused by` of the stacktrace

Comment: Maybe [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-25338) helps?

Comment: @Jens that is same issue. But no clear answer in that question